# Windows Update continually repeats same updates

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

For the last week whenever I shutdown my Windows 7 Home Premium laptop, I get the yellow shield telling me I have updates (both updates are shown below my question). I shutdown the system, the updates download and install. The next time I shutdown my system, the exact thing happens again, with the same updates.

So far I have run the Microsoft Mr. Fixit tool no success, uninstalled and repaired both the .NET Framework 4 extended and the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile, with no success. Any suggestions?

**First update**:

> Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 on XP, Server 2003, Vista, Windows 7, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2 for x64 (KB2600217)
>
> Download size: 32.2 MB
>
> You may need to restart your computer for this update to take effect.
>
> Update type: Recommended
>
> This update addresses stability, reliability, and performance issues in Microsoft .NET Framework 4. After you install this item, you may have to restart your computer.

Comment: You mentioned two updates, but it looks like you only posted one.  Do you have a second?

Answer (score 4):

As an administrator, stop the Windows Update service (Start > Run > services.msc, stop Windows Update). Rename the `%WINDIR%\SoftwareDistribution` directory to something like **SoftwareDistribution.bak** and restart.

Occasionally I've seen updates become "stuck" and cached, prompting the behavior you're seeing. This method normally works for me in most cases.

Comment: How does it help, and what is affected by renaming/removing system folder. Would it stop working at all after that?

Comment: It in effect clears the update cache, giving you a "clean start". When the service is restarted the folder will be recreated by the system. Barring any major underlying system issues. Additional info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509997