# Windows 7 updates getting accumilated

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I have a problem with my company PC which is running Windows 7 and is in active directory. Some administrative actions are disabled in it.

About 3 months ago, several system updates appeared and when I restarted the PC to install updates, one update got left behind. Every time when I shut down PC, this update gets installed. System doesn't report that the update failed, but it appears again and again in next shutdowns too.

After several days, another set of updates appeared. When I restarted the machine to update them, then there were two updates which never gets applied.

Few days back, another set of updates appeared. Now I have 4 updates which never gets applied.

How can I get these updates to install properly? or is there any other way to get rid of them? It takes a lot of time to shut down my PC because every time it tries to install these 4 updates.

Comment: "I have a problem with my company PC" - Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Windows Update continually repeats same updates](https://superuser.com/questions/576515/windows-update-continually-repeats-same-updates/576520#576520)

Also in a command prompt do a >SFC /ScanNow to check overall file system integrity.

One method I have used before to address this problem, I stopped the insanity of the thing basically failing automated, To try and do the same update Manuel, and to learn what or why.

Find the KB# of the update, find that artical on microsoft site that tells about it.  Read what it does and any pre-requisites it has.  Read about what files it was going to replace. Read any interesting things that may be presented on how it Fails.  Understand ~20% of what is going on (at least:-).
Then find the seperate installer package for that update, which can be made for deployers and can usually be found as a single item to manually download and install.

Why would the seperate update that manually installs work correct when the automated one fails? , could be related back up there to the First thing, the download cache was flawed.  . Other clues exist within the MS information and data about a specific update, you finally have a way better idea of what is going on, and what may be failing because of changes you made, or software. It could be it is installing something that you dont even want or need, or does not even apply to your computer.

For any single specific update , just like installing any specific program, it helps (again) to discover the name of the update the KB#, then web search for that specific update number , here or on the rest of the web. That will also get you much better information , vses a general "updates are failing" (they do that). Even the above question could have included the KBnumber of the updates your specifically having troubles with.

Comment: The answer for the related question you gave removed updates getting installed in every shutdown.